# Laravel 5.7: Eloquent Pivot fields not being casted with sync()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following Eloquent Models with a many to many relationship:

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function products() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->using('App\UserProductPivot')
            ->withPivot('label', 'is_primary', 'sort_order')
    }
}

class Product extends Model 
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => "string"
    ];
}
```

And as shown in the product relationship of the user I'm using a custom intermediate table model 'App\UserProductPivot':

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserStationPivot extends Pivot {
    protected $casts = ['product_id' => 'string'];
}
```

Pivot table migration:

```
 Schema::create('station_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('product_id');
    $table->boolean('is_primary')->nullable();
    $table->string('label')->nullable();
    $table->integer('sort_order');
    $table->primary(['user_id', 'product_id']);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**The problem**

Inside a method of the User Model:

```
$array = [23456 => [
    "is_primary" => true
    "label" => "Test"
    "sort_order" => 1
  ],
  "138seq" => [
    "is_primary" => false
    "label" => "Test"
    "sort_order" => 2
]];
$this->products()->sync($array);
```

With the given setup I expected 'product_id' 23456 to be casted to a string but when calling sync() it results in a SQL error on the product_id field as it was not casted to a string.. What is going wrong?

Comment: why are you using foreign keys as string ? change them to integer you have ways to do it without losing data

Comment: @WalterCejas You are suggesting that I modify the primary key of the Product model to an integer? The product model is seeded from a 3rd party and and the Id is a string.. It feels weird to me to have an actual product id stored but create a extra id column just to have it as integer.. Still left wondering why the casting does not work...

Comment: The casting, as I know, converts the field when you access it (only when you are reading from the DB) to that selected type (string or array etc..).
Maybe, you have to set a mutator, converting that field to string in the insertions..

Comment: @WalterCejas "Now with Laravel 5.5, the $casts property on the Eloquent\Model and Eloquent\Relations\Pivot classes will behave the same. Laravel will “respect” your casts on both, whether you’re reading, inserting or updating data." What I have found said that changed as of 5.5...  :(

Comment: I am facing a similar problem but with a `boolean`, with `sync()` if this column change, it is not stored in the database.